# Google Apps Script to Copy a given folder using UI Prompt for target folder name

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to copy a given folder and its contents (sub folders and files) to a new folder using a simple Ui Prompt for the target folder name.

This is my updated script after suggestions from Meera:

```
function start() {
  var sourceFolder = 'SourceFolderName'; // Folder exists in Drive
  var source = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolder);

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var folderPrompt = ui.prompt('Enter the Target Folder Name');
  Logger.log(folderPrompt.getResponseText());
    if (folderPrompt.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK){
      var target = folderPrompt.getResponseText();

    if (source.hasNext()) {
    copyFolder(source.next(), target);
  }

  Logger.log(target);

function copyFolder(source, target) {
  var folders = source.getFolders();
  var files = source.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target);
  var target_folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(target); // Added as per Meera
  var target = target_folder.next(); // Added as per Meera
}

  while (folders.hasNext()) {
  var subFolder = folders.next();
  var folderName = subFolder.getName();
  var targetFolder = target.createFolder(folderName);
  copyFolder(subFolder, targetFolder);
}
}
}
}
```

The prompt box still displays but after entering the folder name and selecting OK nothing happens. Still no new target folder is created.

Comment: Do you mind formatting the code in the question a bit better? Also, it looks like you're passing `target` as string to `File.makeCopy` function. You need to pass it a `Folder` object.

Comment: same sentiments with vinkomlacic, please do indent the code properly.

Comment: Where do you want the copied folders to be in? it is not clear from the code. Also, from the code the `function copyFolder` is not properly separated and therefore not being called, you can debug the code or use `Logger.log()` on different places to know where the script goes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you have a folder in your google Drive with the name "SourceFolderName" as you entered in line 2 of code. Else change the value to any existing folder name.
Also in the copyFolder function, the `file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target);` will not work as target is just the name(string) of the target folder. You have to add below two lines of code to get the folder `var target_folder=DriveApp.getFoldersByName(target);var target=target_folder.next();` [[refer here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname,-destination) ]and the rest will work.

Comment: Hi Meera. The source folder does exist in my Drive. When I add the two lines as indicated I get the following message: TypeError: target.createFolder is not a function. Here is the amended code as suggested: while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
      file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target);
      var target_folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(target);
      var target = target_folder.next();
  }

Comment: The line file.makeCopy(file.getName(),target);should come after the two lines of code i suggested

Comment: Answer given by kessy follows that logic and should solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for `target.createFolder is not a function`.

When passing the target it is a string. Using the method `getFoldersByName` for the target folder as well you can get a folder instead of a string.

I have modified the script like:

```js
function start() {
  var sourceFolder = 'sourceFolder';
  var targetFolder;
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var folderPrompt = ui.prompt('Enter the Target Folder Name');
  //Logger.log(folderPrompt.getResponseText());
  if (folderPrompt.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    targetFolder = folderPrompt.getResponseText();
  }

  var source = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolder);
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(targetFolder);

  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
  }

  if (source.hasNext()) {
    copyFolder(source.next(), folder);
  }
}

function copyFolder(source, target) {
  var folders = source.getFolders();
  var files = source.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target);
  }

  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var subFolder = folders.next();
    var folderName = subFolder.getName();
    var targetFolder = target.createFolder(folderName);
    copyFolder(subFolder, targetFolder);
  }
}
```